# Sencha Touch 2 App won't run in iOS6 Simulator but runs on Device

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch-2, ios6

I'm not sure what the issue is here, maybe someone can shed some light on what could be happening. I'm developing an Sencha Touch app wrapped in Phonegap 2.1.  Ever since updating to Xcode 4.5 and the iOS6 simulator the app no longer loads the scripts defined in my index.html. These scripts, however load normally running directly on an IOS6 device. I also have installed the 4.3, 5.0, and 5.1 Simulators.  The only simulator that works properly is the 5.1 simulator. Any ideas on what could be happening here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also you can try resetting the iOS Simulator by selecting iPhone Simulator > Reset Content and Settings

Answer (score 1):

Write this line in app.js and it will work in simulator 6..

Ext.Viewport.setAutoMaximize(true);